# Travel medical insurance validity - should it cover whole visa period or my time in Schengen?

Tags: schengen

Should the insurance cover only days I'm physically in Schengen area? Including the days I enter and leave Schengen?

or should it cover the whole visa duration?

I already have the visa (Type D, 2 entry)

Comment: I don't know but it is worth checking annual muliti-trip policies.  Often, they are not much more than one single trip policy and better if you make a second trip.

Comment: @badjohn That is true if you are diligent enough to cancel them when no longer needed. It is a common business scheme to sell you an annual travel insurance with an automatic annual renewal hoping that a lot of customers will keep and pay this for years even if they only make a single trip.

Answer (score 2):

The insurance should cover you when you are inside the Schengen area. It is wise to include the complete travel from home till back home.

If you have to stay longer for an emergency the policy usually covers the extra time.